# Assign a string based on sequence in the string - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a text in one of the cell in a table in Oracle SQL:

```
ISA*00*AUTHORIZAT*00*SECURITY I*ZZ*000000060000000*ZZ*000000010000000*110705*1132*^*00501*110705001*0*T*:~
GS*HC*00000006*00000001*20110705*113253*110705001*X*005010X222A1~
ST*837*0021*005010X222~
BHT*0019*00*244579*20061015*1023*CH~
NM1*41*2*PREMIER BILLING SERVICE*****46*TGJ23~
PER*IC*JERRY*TE*3055552222*EX*231~
NM1*40*2*KEY INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*66783JJT~
HL*1**20*1~
PRV*BI*PXC*203BF0100Y~
NM1*85*2*BEN KILDARE SERVICE*****XX*9876543210~
N3*234 SEAWAY ST~
N4*MIAMI*FL*33111~
```

Please note the above is in 1 cell. I need to break it down in multiple rows and assign a loop on it.

The table would look like:

```
loop        message
000         ISA*00*AUTHORIZAT*00*SECURITY I*ZZ*000000060000000*ZZ*000000010000000*110705*1132*^*00501*110705001*0*T*:~
000         GS*HC*00000006*00000001*20110705*113253*110705001*X*005010X222A1~
000         ST*837*0021*005010X222~
000         BHT*0019*00*244579*20061015*1023*CH~
1000A       NM1*41*2*PREMIER BILLING SERVICE*****46*TGJ23~
1000A       PER*IC*JERRY*TE*3055552222*EX*231~
1000B       NM1*40*2*KEY INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*66783JJT~
2000A       HL*1**20*1~
2010AA      PRV*BI*PXC*203BF0100Y~
2010AA      NM1*85*2*BEN KILDARE SERVICE*****XX*9876543210~
2010AA      N3*234 SEAWAY ST~
2010AA      N4*MIAMI*FL*33111~
```

So, basically, I need to split the string based on new line and then assign appropriate loop based on the sequence. The rules are:

- First NM1 should be 1000A and continue assigning till next NM1
- Next NM1 should be 1000B and continue assigning till next PRV
- Next PRV should be 2010AA and continue assigning till next NM1

I was able to successfully break the text into multiple lines using regex, but am not able to assign values based on the conditions.

Is there a way to code it in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ISA*00*AUTHORIZAT*00*SECURITY I*ZZ*000000060000000*ZZ*000000010000000*110705*1132*^*00501*110705001*0*T*:~
GS*HC*00000006*00000001*20110705*113253*110705001*X*005010X222A1~
ST*837*0021*005010X222~
BHT*0019*00*244579*20061015*1023*CH~
NM1*41*2*PREMIER BILLING SERVICE*****46*TGJ23~
PER*IC*JERRY*TE*3055552222*EX*231~
NM1*40*2*KEY INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*66783JJT~
HL*1**20*1~
PRV*BI*PXC*203BF0100Y~
NM1*85*2*BEN KILDARE SERVICE*****XX*9876543210~
N3*234 SEAWAY ST~
N4*MIAMI*FL*33111~'
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH rsqfc ( value, line, rn, max_rn, nm1, prv, depth ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.+?(' || CHR(10) || '|$)', 1, 1 ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( value, '.+?(' || CHR(10) || '|$)' ) - 1,
         CASE SUBSTR( value, 1, 4 ) WHEN 'NM1*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         CASE SUBSTR( value, 1, 4 ) WHEN 'PRV*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         CASE SUBSTR( value, 1, 4 ) WHEN 'NM1*' THEN 1 WHEN 'PRV*' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
  FROM   test_data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.+?(' || CHR(10) || '|$)', 1, rn + 1 ),
         rn + 1,
         max_rn,
         CASE SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.+?(' || CHR(10) || '|$)', 1, rn + 1 ), 1, 4 ) WHEN 'NM1*' THEN nm1 + 1 ELSE nm1 END,
         CASE SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.+?(' || CHR(10) || '|$)', 1, rn + 1 ), 1, 4 ) WHEN 'PRV*' THEN prv + 1 ELSE prv END,
         CASE SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '.+?(' || CHR(10) || '|$)', 1, rn + 1 ), 1, 4 ) WHEN 'NM1*' THEN 1 WHEN 'PRV*' THEN 2 ELSE depth END
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  rn < max_rn
)
SELECT CASE depth
       WHEN 2 THEN '2010A' || CHR( 64 + prv )
       WHEN 1 THEN '1000' || CHR( 64 + nm1 )
       WHEN 0 THEN '000'
       END AS "LOOP",
       line
FROM   rsqfc;
```

**Output**:

```
LOOP   | LINE                                                                                                          
:----- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
000    | ISA*00*AUTHORIZAT*00*SECURITY I*ZZ*000000060000000*ZZ*000000010000000*110705*1132*^*00501*110705001*0*T*:~<br>
000    | GS*HC*00000006*00000001*20110705*113253*110705001*X*005010X222A1~<br>                                         
000    | ST*837*0021*005010X222~<br>                                                                                   
000    | BHT*0019*00*244579*20061015*1023*CH~<br>                                                                      
1000A  | NM1*41*2*PREMIER BILLING SERVICE*****46*TGJ23~<br>                                                            
1000A  | PER*IC*JERRY*TE*3055552222*EX*231~<br>                                                                        
1000B  | NM1*40*2*KEY INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*66783JJT~<br>                                                           
1000B  | HL*1**20*1~<br>                                                                                               
2010AA | PRV*BI*PXC*203BF0100Y~<br>                                                                                    
1000C  | NM1*85*2*BEN KILDARE SERVICE*****XX*9876543210~<br>                                                           
1000C  | N3*234 SEAWAY ST~<br>
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ec0a779862948d04effbc16975624824)*

Comment: I have to add many such rules. I mean for next NM1 till next ABC, assign 3000A. Then next XYZ to QQQ, assign 4000A. Where should I add those rules in the query?

Comment: Also, how did you do 1000A, 1000B and 1000C? I have to assign custom text depending on the conditions.

Comment: @dang No idea, there is no data with those codes in your sample input and it us unclear what your additional requirements involve. This is intended to answer the question you have originally asked and not something with moving goal posts. If you want to add additional requirements then ask a new question with a [MCVE] including sample data illustrating your new requirements the corresponding expected output and a link back to this question.

Comment: `A` is represented by the ASCII code 65, `B` by 66, `C` by 67 so to get the values then you concatenate the string `1000` with the character given by the ASCII code `64 + nm1` that is what `'1000' || CHR( 64 + nm1 )` is doing.